# Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $b^n + n$ is a multiple of $a^n + n$ for all natural numbers $n$. Prove that $a = b$.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $b^n + n$ is a multiple of $a^n + n$ for all natural numbers $n$. Prove that $a = b$.

Here is my start:
$a^n + n | b^n + n$,
$a^n + n | b^n - a^n$
$a^n + n|(b - a)(b^{n-1} + ab^{n-2}... + a^{n-2} b + a^{n-1})$
Now we attempt to prove $b - a = 0$ by proving $a^n +n$ does not divide $(b^{n-1} + ab^{n-2}... + a^{n-2} b + a^{n-1})$. If we prove this successfully then we have $a^n + n | b-a$ for all $n$ and clearly $a=b$.
I do not know if this method is valid, though I have had a hard time proving $a^n +n$ does not divide $(b^{n-1} + ab^{n-2}... + a^{n-2} b + a^{n-1})$ which leads me to suspect I am missing a more clever approach.

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988167/if-for-all-n-in-bbbn-an-n-divides-bn-n-then-a-b) is similar.

Comment: The above linked question is further linked to [this identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2896839/89922).

Comment: I explain how to *discover* a proof in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1196023/242).